# Emacs scrollbar customize

Tags: emacs

I customized my emacs, fonts, background and etc... But scrollbar remained the same color that was. How to change the color of scrollbar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(set-face-background 'scroll-bar "green")
```